Avodah Zarah and non-Jewish houseworkers
Does a Jewish homeowner need to be concerned that non-Jewish maids might perform idol worship with his possessions?
Would this make any of the things in his house forbidden, or no?
What precautions is  he obligated to take to prevent his things from becoming forbidden?
I am concerned about food, as well as non-food, items.

אין אדם אוסר דבר שאינו שלו

@shmosel that's not true. We assume  idol worshippers have sex with animals and libate wine when unattended.

Great to have you here! Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi. Your question as currently formatted appears to be a solicitation for such personalized advice. As such the community will likely vote to close this question. Questions can be edited in order to be brought back in line with site policy.

@ClintEastwood those are the exceptions to the rule.

Why my text is edited - chutzpah!

My text states if a Jew has a housemaid and she does avodah zara things on the owner objects without that the Jewish owner is aware of…

I edited your text to save the question. It was phrased in a way that was beneath the standards of the site and had several votes to close.
